# What's the best way to fight an Enderman?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When you're looking at one and it's running at you really fast, you know you're in deep trouble.

[image]

My question is: What is the best tactic to fight an Enderman because they seem to teleport behind you or on your side which makes it kind of hard to deal with them.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Run into the closest water (or lay some down) or get on a boat -- water damages them too.  So when they teleport next to you, they're being damaged from the water at the same time that you're hitting them with the sword.  Firing a bow from a boat is the best idea if you're taking this strategy.

If you're not near water, run away and shoot at them with your bow.  If you can, charge the bow fully, but charging the bow slows your movement.  This tactic is less effective in water because your movement speed is reduced.

If you have to engage them with your sword, jump up and hit them on the downward fall of the jump.  This will give you a critical hit with your sword, and so help you kill the Ender Man quicker.

Be prepared: full armour, bucket of water, full hunger meter and a good sword!

Comment: bear in mind you can't hit them with a bow that doesn't have the flame enchantment, because they will dodge the arrows and teleport away

Comment: Don't enderman teleport away when you shoot an arrow at them?

Answer (score 14):

If you attack their legs with a weapon (I don't think it works with fists), they will not teleport.

Something I do while farming them in The End is build a 3x3 roof over my head that is 3 blocks high. 2 blocks of air let me traverse it freely, but Endermen cannot enter and just run into the ceiling blocks. At which point I can just pick them off freely.

Answer (score 9):

Endermen are now immune to bows without the 'Flame' enchantment.

In my opinion, you need 3 to 5 buckets of water or lava, fully enchanted armor and/or sword, a bow with the 'Flame' enchantment, and some boats, as well as a pumpkin for wearing on your head.

You should wear the pumpkin because when you look at an Enderman through it, they will not turn hostile towards you. However, this restricts your view a lot, so you want to do this as little as possible. You can wear the pumpkin by dragging it from your inventory into the place where you normally equip your helmet. Note that the Endermen **will** turn hostile if you hit them first, so be careful.

Comment: If you are using a pumpkin it's easier in f5 mode.

Answer (score 4):

you need to build a small shelter that is only two blocks tall. Endermen are three blocks tall and cannot walk under your shelter. Now you can attack their legs all you want with your sword as long as you are in your shelter. Your shelter doesn't need walls on a roof with a two high space for you to walk under it.

Answer (score 1):

Endermen are actually easy to kill if you're careful. First, make sure that the area around the Enderman is free from other mobs. Walk up close to the Enderman, put a pumpkin on your head, and grab a good sword. Then find the Enderman through the pumpkin and whack him. If you have the knockback enchantment, he will disappear from view for a moment, but keep swinging your sword at about his waist level and he will walk back into it. If you're careful, you will kill him in a few strokes.

Answer (score 0):

You should just run away; it's probably the best idea. They can't harm you if you're in your house. Plus, don't get scared of the screeching. Take out their legs. Do anything you have to do. Be safe.

Comment: They can still harm you if you are in your house... the same way a creeper can still explode in your territory.

Answer (score -3):

Wear a pumpkin! I know you can't see with it on your head, but it scares the Enderman! PROTIP - Press F1 with a pumpkin on your head.

Comment: Once the endermen is provoked, the pumpkin will not prevent an endermen from attacking. You can, however, look at them safely, if you wear one. Also the pumpkin was already mentioned.

Comment: Welcome to [gaming.se]! Before getting started, you may want to look at the [faq] to see how to answer questions as well as ask good ones. :)