# How do I heal in Minecraft Beta 1.8?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm eating a load of cooked pork chops but my health isn't increasing, what do I do?

Comment: Related question: [How does food work in Minecraft?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/30036/how-does-food-work-in-minecraft)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

here is the article on the minecraft wiki on [Food](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Food) and [Health](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Hearts)

> As of 1.8, health is not restored by consuming food, but rather slowly regenerates when the player's "Food Bar" is full.

and [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/The_Player)

> In the 1.8 update, the food mechanic was changed-- No longer does eating food regain health, but instead fills the Hunger Meter, which goes down when the player does things like running, sprinting, and mining. When the player has 9 or more meat bones on the hunger meter, their health will slowly regenerate.

Comment: So theres no outside way to heal your health anymore, ei maybe a potion, you just gotta keep your health at or about 80% x.x

Comment: @RokonOrichiami As of 1.9 you can make a instant health potion see: http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Brewing

Answer (score 7):

You (should) auto regen health when your food bar is full. Food no longer directly heals you.

Answer (score -3):

Always eat a golden apple or eat something normal such as a apple. When you eat your hunger bar refills and your health will slowly regenerate!

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! You might want to visit the [about](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/about) and [help](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help) pages to better understand how our site functions, particularly the "[How do I write a good answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)" section.

Comment: Additionally most of your answer was covered by the previous two answers nearly two years ago and doesn't contribute much else. Golden apples might have been something worth expanding upon, as they do provide some additional health-related bonuses beyond the hunger bar.

Comment: This answer is too short and vague. you didn't even explain how to get a golden apple.