# How does the degrading of the food bar work?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

While searching for an answer to my question, I am came across another question on this website: [How does Food work in Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/30036/how-does-food-work-in-minecraft).

Here, the answer provided by ["Nick T"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/2259/nick-t) states that:

> Various actions including walking, swimming, running, and stabbing
>   things will increase your hunger (though [notably not boating](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/39037/how-hungry-will-i-get-from-a-boat-trip/39038#39038)).

There are 2 questions I want to ask. **Firstly, besides walking, swimming, running and stabbing, are there other actions that deplete your hunger?** For example, Mining or Jumping?

**Secondly, what is the rate in which the following actions deplete your Hunger Bar? Do different actions have different effects on your hunger bar?**

Comment: I don't have time to make a proper answer now, but everything can be found on the wiki page [here](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Hunger)

Comment: The three most depleting actions are (in order): regenerating, sprinting, and food poisoning.

Comment: In which case it needs updating- it's two years old and predates healing draining your hunger bar.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are **three aspects** to hunger in Minecraft.

1. **Food Level:** Visible from the hunger bar. Presented as **ten drumstick icons**. Each icon represents two hunger points, for a maximum of 20 (when full). Replenished by eating food. Amount is dependent on food type.
2. **Food Saturation Level:** Not visible to the player. The **player's hunger will not decrease until their food saturation level reaches 0**. The hunger bar will **shake/jitter** when food saturation is at 0. Replenished by eating food. Amount is dependent on food type.
3. **Food Exhaustion Level:** Not visible to the player. Value can range from 0.0 to 4.0. **Once it reaches 4.0, food saturation is reduced by 1.0 and the exhaustion level resets to 0.0**. If food saturation is already at 0.0, the player will lose a hunger point (half a drumstick).

Here's a list of the **actions which increase your exhaustion level**, and by how much.

- Walking/sneaking - 0.01 per metre
- Swimming - 0.0125 per metre
- Breaking a block - 0.025
- Sprinting - 0.1 per metre
- Jumping - 0.2
- Attacking an enemy - 0.3
- Receiving any damage - 0.3
- Effects of food poisoning (raw chicken/rotten flesh) - 0.5 per second (15.0 total)
- Effects of food poisoning (pufferfish) - 1.5 per second (22.5 total)
- Sprinting jump - 0.8
- Regeneration one health point - 3.0

For further reading and specific information on how different types of food affect saturation, visit the wiki page for Hunger: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Hunger