# How do you kill an Enderman without them teleporting?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I tried to kill and Enderman by it's leg because I was told that it's easier but they just keep Teleporting away.

Comment: Hi Jacob, and welcome to Arqade! Have a look at [this question and its answers](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/30022/whats-the-best-way-to-fight-those-enderman); I think it'll help you.

Comment: don't look at them just swing away at the legs